# ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> vs ArrayList<Object>

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, adapter, android-viewholder

Will there be any problem if I use `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` in place of `ArrayList<Object>` for populating a `recyclerView`? or am I the only weirdo present here?

I have image links in each of the list items. Some also don't have any image links.

I'm saving the images for the first time when displaying the list then fetching the images from sdcard if image name matches. I also have unique image names.

When I'm scrolling my view, the items that does not contain any images also showing the previously loaded images but it is not duplicating the texts.

I'm also using

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

These functions in my adapter.

Adapter.java

```
public class ChatBoxAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChatBoxAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView text,date;
    public ImageView image;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
        date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
        image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
    }
}

Context context;
Bitmap bitmap;

public ChatBoxAdapter(Context _context) {
    context = _context;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_chat_box, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    String comment = Base.chatdatalist.get(position).get(3);
    String image_url = Base.chatdatalist.get(position).get(4);
    String date = Base.chatdatalist.get(position).get(5);

    File imageFile = null;

    if (image_url.startsWith(Base.baseUrl)) {

        String image_name = image_url.substring(image_url.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
        imageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Pictures/TMS Sent Images/" + image_name);
        bitmap = null;
        if (imageFile.exists()) {

            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

            long img_size = imageFile.length() / 1024;
            if (img_size <= 200)
                options.inSampleSize = 4;
            else
                options.inSampleSize = 8;

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.toString(), options);
        }
    }

    holder.text.setText(Html.fromHtml(comment, null, new MyTagHandler()));

    if (position !=0 && !chat_date.equals(Base.chatdatalist.get(position - 1).get(15)))
        holder.date.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    if (position == 0)
        holder.date.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    if (bitmap != null) {
        holder.image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        holder.image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else
        if (image_url.startsWith(Base.baseUrl)) {
            holder.image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Picasso.with(context).load(image_url).into(holder.image);
        }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return Base.chatdatalist.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
}
```

What can be the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this question is not clear, you having an arraylist of arraylists suggests there is a one-to-many type of relationship with your data, e.g, one list item may have several paths, is that the case?

Comment: and those functions are in most adapters, post your full adapter code

Comment: Yes… suppose I have an array list commentData, I can do `commentData.add(arrayList);`

Comment: Are you trying to store ArrayLists with a String value in an ArrayList? To what purpose?

Comment: In place of ArrayList<Object> I'm just using ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>. Is it wrong? The purpose is I felt it very easy to implement and store…

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you dont mind casting every time: `ArrayList<String> foo = (ArrayList<String>) commentData.get(i)` as opposed to `ArrayList<String> x = commentsData.get(i)` sure, use `ArrayList<Object>`

Comment: I use commentData.get(i).get(j);

Comment: do you understand the advantages of specifying `<String>` on a `List`?

Comment: List containing String object?

Comment: yep, it specifies that the collection will contain Strings only, thus you dont need to cast to a type when u need to extract from the collection

Comment: so either approach doesnt really make much of a difference in terms of accessibility, just choose one and run with it

Comment: Yes in the same way ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> is working. There is no need for any kind of casting.

Comment: What do you mean "working" ?  are u using it to `setText()` somewhere?